# Merge two tables (CSV) if (table1 column A == table2 column A)

Tags: python, excel, csv, formatting

I have two CSV's, openable in Numbers or Excel, structured:
`| word | num1 |`
 and
`| word | num2 |`

if the two words are equal (like they're both 'hi' and 'hi') I want it to become:
`| word | num1 | num2 |`

here are some pictures:

[image: table1]
[image: table2]

So like for row 1, since both the words are the same, 'TRUE', I want it to become something like
`| TRUE | 5.371748 | 4.48957 |`

Either through some small script, or if there's some feature/ function I'm overlooking.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict:

```
with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as file_a, open('file2.csv', 'rb') as file_b:
    data_a = csv.reader(file_a)
    data_b = dict(csv.reader(file_b))  # <-- dict
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as file_out:
        csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)
        for word, num_a in data_a:
            csv_out.writerow([word, num_a, data_b.get(word, '')])  # <-- edit
```

(untested)

Comment: On the right track, but it's putting a comma between *each and every* character. [See?](http://i.imgur.com/kUJ1gFR.png). What should I change?

Comment: Oops! There were a pair of brackets missing. Please see my edit.

Comment: That works almost perfectly. Is there anyway to add words to the dict that *don't* exist in both csv's? For instance lets say there is a word in the first csv that isn't in the second, can you add just the word and the number from the first csv, leaving the third column blank?

Answer (score 4):

For `csv`, I always reach for the data analysis library `pandas`. http://pandas.pydata.org/

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', names=['word','num1'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', names=['word','num2'])
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='word')
df3.to_csv('merged_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), to let you iterate the two CSVs in lock-step:

```
with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as f1, open('file2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
    r1, r2 = csv.reader(f1), csv.reader(f2)
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as fout:
        w = csv.writer(fout)
        for row1, row2 in zip(r1, r2):
            if row1[0] == row2[0]:
                w.writerow([row1[0], row1[1], row2[1]])
```

I'm not sure what you wanted to happen if they're *not* equal. Maybe insert both rows, like this?

```
            else:
                w.writerow([row1[0], row1[1], ''])
                w.writerow([row2[0], '', row2[1]])
```

Comment: That *almost* works. The thing is my first two csv files aren't 'synced'... End up with problems like [this](http://i.imgur.com/lJHKI41.png) (notice the double entry of '100%').

Comment: @AndrewSB: You need to explain what you actually want to do. Give us some (small) sample input and the expected output, explaining anything that isn't obvious.