# Python compare two xls files for matching elements

Tags: python, excel

I'm new in python.My idea is to write script,which gets elements from file "file1.xls" col 1 and number of items on col 2, compare col 1  with elements in col 1 in file "file2.xls",and if there is a match in "file3.xls" writes :
matching string from col 1 (in file2.xls)
item name which is on same row but col 2 (in file2.xls)
item weight which is on same row but col 3 (in file2.xls)
number of items from file 1 col 2 
So far with scripts which i found and mod in this site i do the job with reading file 1 and write it to file 3.I use multiple if statements and in them i put information from file2.xls.But that was the way of doing job 1996 when I last wrote on Paskal :).I believe that there is other way - the Python way. Sorry for my English and thanks in advance for all of you. Have a nice day

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/~/User/Desktop/program/file1.xls")
book1 = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/~/User/Desktop/program/file3.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
wb = copy(book1)
s = wb.get_sheet(0)
for r in xrange(2, sheet.nrows):
    d = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    items.append(d)
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/~/User/Desktop/program/file2.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
```

here is where i need help

items contain list of element from col 1 of file1.xls
i want to compare every element from items 
to every element from col 1 of file2.xls
if there is a match in file3.xls i want to write col 1 col 2 and col 3 from file2.xls 
for writting i use s.write(x,0,' matching items ')

Comment: You can read excel file with `xlrd` module

Comment: Yes I do it and write it with xlwt.I need loop which get data from file1.xls col 1 compare it with file2.xls col 1 and if there is a match write matching element,gets col 2 from file2.xls which contain item_name get col 3 which contain gross_weight and save it  in file3.xls. I believe it will be lool in the loop :) but I cant express it. If element 1 match element 2 then item id = data from col 2 , item_weight = data from col 3 and write it to file.3 Something like that

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Merge two tables (CSV) if (table1 column A == table2 column A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768722/merge-two-tables-csv-if-table1-column-a-table2-column-a)

If your input files can be CSVs, then this might be exactly what you're looking for.

If your files have to be .xls, then you can use `xlrd` and `xlwt` in Python (which it seems you've already found!).