# Compare many csv files to produce an output

Tags: python, csv, compare

I'm trying to write a python script to compare prices of some products. 
I have multiple csv files, for example file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv. 
Every csv file has the same format, for example:

```
File1.csv
Barcode    Description    Price  
1111111    Descr1         1.2   
1111112    Descr2         3.5  
1111113    Descr3         7.0  
2222222    DescrX         4.3  
etc..    

File2.csv
Barcode    Description    Price  
1111113    Descr3         8.0   
1111112    Descr2         3.0  
1111114    Descr4         11.3  
etc..
```

Rows in the files don't appear in the same sequence, and sometimes the description of the same product varies in different files. The only thing that can be the same in different files is the barcode.
The goal I'm trying to achieve is to obtain an output csv file like that:

```
Output.csv
Barcode    Description    Price1    Price2    ...    PriceX
1111111    Descr1         1.2
1111112    Descr2         3.5       3.0  
1111113    Descr3         7.0       8.0
1111114    Descr4                   11.3
2222222    DescrX         4.3
```

The output have to show me all the prices for a given product.
The only similar thing I found is this: [Merge two tables (CSV) if (table1 column A == table2 column A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768722/merge-two-tables-csv-if-table1-column-a-table2-column-a) 
But it can handle only two csv files, and if a barcode in file2 doesn't match a barcode in file1, then it doesn't appear in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a python dictionary where the key is the Barcode and the value is the the description and the array of all prices for the product.

Go through each CSV and add the products to this dictionary and after you finished parsing every CSV file, just iterate through the dictionary and output the data into a new output CSV.